# Attaching shower head arm escutcheon to wall

Tags: plumbing, shower, plumbing-fixture

My contractor left all three shower heads in our house in this condition (*see photo*). I can slide the escutcheon (*trim plate*) up to the wall but it doesn't stay put.

What's the correct way to finish it?

Plumber's putty inside the plate with silicone caulk around the edge?

[image: Shower head trim with wall hole]

[image: Empty shower trim plate plus OP's reflection]

Answer (score 6):

Those are intended to be friction-fit--the wavy tabs you see from the back grab the shower nipple. You might be able to remove the shower head, slide the trim plate off the nipple, flex the tabs a bit with a pliers, and reinstall.

However, a dab of clear silicone caulk could help keep it in place. Put the caulk far enough back on the nipple that it won't ooze out the front of the joint.

One other thought... if the trim rings move because there's a lot of movement in the shower head pipe (in the wall), that's a problem. It should've been secured near the nipple connection. If that's the case, some low-expansion spray foam would really help.

Comment: Thanks. So the silicone caulk should contact the center hole of the plate with the tabs (the flange? not sure if you would call it that?) as opposed to the outer edge where it meets the tile, correct?

Comment: Right. I don't ever caulk around plumbing fixtures if I can help it. It ruins the aesthetic of the situation.

Answer (score 0):

Using a caulking gun with silicone shoot enough into the tile opening until it starts to come out. let it push out until slightly higher than the tile surface. Shoot some more onto the inside of the trim plate's outer edge so that when pressed to the tile wall it will adhere.

Comment: The tile opening opens up into the wall. Do you mean just caulk around the edges?

Comment: You should fill the opening to prevent water from getting behind the wall. You should also caulk around the plate for the same reason.